# How can I use exit codes to run shell scripts sequentially?

Tags: linux, build, integration, scripting, continuous

Since cruise control is full of bugs that have wasted my entire week, I have decided the existing shell scripts I have are simpler and thus better.

Here is what I have so far

```
svn update /var/www/k12/
#svn log --revision "HEAD" /var/www/code/  | head -2 | tail -1 | awk '{print $1}' > /var/www/path/version.txt

# upload the files
rsync -ar --verbose --stats --progress --delete --exclude=*.svn /var/www/code/ example.com:/home/path

# bring database up to date
ssh example.com 'php /path/tasks/dbrefactor.php'

# notify me
ssh example.com 'php /path/tasks/build.php'
```

Only thing is the other day I changed the paths and forgot to update the rsync call. As a result the "notify me" step ran several times while I was figuring stuff out.

I know in linux you can do `command1 && command2` and if command 1 "fails" command2 will not run, but how can I observe the "failure/success" exit codes for debugging purposes. Some of the scripts I wrote myself and I'm sure I will need to do something special.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exit code of a previous process happens to be in `$?` variable right after its execution. Usually (that's not required, but it's the convention everyone follows) the exit code of a successful command will be equal to `0`, and any other value means an error.

Remember of the caveats! One of them is that after these commands:

```
svn log --revision "HEAD" /var/www/code/  | head -2 | tail -1 | awk '{print $1}'
echo "$?"
```

the zero result would most likely be returned, because in the `$?` the *return code of `awk`* is contained.  To avoid it, set the `pipefail` option somewhere above the code:

```
set -o pipefail 1
```

Comment: Josh, since you have more than 15 reputation, you might want and are able to "vote up" to the answers you liked and/or found useful--try the buttons near the big numbers.

Answer (score 4):

The best option, especially for unattended scripts, is to set the `-e` shell option:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
```

or

```
set -e
```

This will cause the shell to stop executing if any (untested) command exits with a nonzero error code.

```
          -e      Exit  immediately if a simple command (see SHELL GRAMMAR
                  above) exits with a non-zero status.  The shell does not
                  exit  if  the  command that fails is part of an until or
                  while loop, part of an if statement, part of a && or  ||
                  list, or if the command's return value is being inverted
                  via !.  A trap on ERR, if set, is  executed  before  the
                  shell exits.
```

Comment: The (nonzero) exit code detected by the shell will be the return value of the shell when it returns. So you would use `$?` after the shell script exits.

Answer (score 1):

The return value of the last-run command is stored in the variable `$?`. You can use that to determine which command to run next. [Overview of special variables.](http://www.nongnu.org/lpi-manuals/lpi-102/html/ch07s02.html#id318209)

Answer (score 1):

i think $? contains the last exit code

```
if [[ -z $? ]]
then
  # notify me
  ssh example.com 'php /path/tasks/build.php'
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you can use the exit non zero at the points where the failure is expected and before processing step further you will check 
if [ $? -neq 0 ]
then there is a failure.

---

The $? will always return a non zero number if the last process does not executed successfully.